# Display CiviCRM Survey in Drupal Content Type

Tags: drupal, civisurvey

I have created a CiviCRM survey (under Campaigns > New Survey in the CiviCRM menu) but would like to embed this survey into a Drupal Content type. How might I do this?
I am using

- Drupal 7.37
- MySQL 5.6.24
- PHP 5.6.8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By design, a CiviCRM survey can't be displayed anywhere on your website. From [the docs](http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/survey/what-is-civisurvey/) (emphasis mine):

> CiviCampaign has a feature that enables **offline** surveys by providing a standardised way to record survey responses and to then generate reports from the survey data.

If you want an **online** form for your website visitors to fill out, alternatives are [CiviPetition](http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/petition/what-is-civipetition) and [Webform-CiviCRM Integration](https://drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm). For your use case I recommend the latter. Webform-CiviCRM can do everything CiviPettion can do, plus a whole lot more, including the ability to be embedded into drupal content (well, technically a webform *is* drupal content, so you can do anything with it that you can do with other nodes or blocks).

Answer (score 3):

Webform-CiviCRM would meet your requirements and can be provided as a Block if that is what you are after (ie it can be set to show on certain Content Types)